# Shortest and most readable way to create an object based on some properties of another object

Tags: typescript

I'm using typescript and am looking for an easy way of creating an object that contains only some of the properties of the original object, while still using typing etc....

Let say that I have the following interface:

```
export interface ArticleModel {
    slug?: string;
    title?: string;
    description?: string;
    body?: string;
    tagList?: string[];
    createdAt?: Date;
    updatedAt?: Date;
    favorited?: boolean;
    favoritesCount?: number;
    author?: ProfileModel;
}
```

And I want to create an object somewhere with only the `title`, `description` and `body`
the obvious way would be:

```
function myFunction(a: ArticleModel) {
    return {
        title: a.title,
        description: a.description,
        body: a.body
    }
}
```

But I think it's too much code - I want this shorter and easier.

I tried the following:

```
function myFunction(a: ArticleModel) {
    let { title, description, body } = a;
    return { title, description, body };
}
```

Still too much code - I would love it if I could reduce this to one line something like the following code, that I know is wrong:

```
function myFunction(a: ArticleModel) {
    return { title, description, body } =a;
}
```

I feel there is a syntax somewhere to do it, but I don't know it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
function myFunction({ title, description, body }: ArticleModel) {
    return  { title, description, body };
}
```

Note that your function lacks a return type by the way, not ideal. You can use the [Pick utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) to make a reduced version of the original type to return.

Comment: @Noam - I don't think you'll get it any shorter than this and be typesafe. The repetition is unfortunately necessary.

Comment: @ daan - Meh, on a trivial function like this the return type seems like overkill; TypeScript will infer it correctly and there's little chance of you changing the function such that it breaks its contract without meaning to. :-) Matter of style though.

Comment: Yeah, the decision on when to duck in and out of typed land is of course a question of style and preference, and the flexibility to do so is one of the great things  about TS. I've run into enough stupid little bugs when I omitted the return type that I tend to err on the side of caution these days :)

Answer (score 0):

You could write an implementation of the [Pick utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys):

```
function pick<T, K extends keyof T>(source: T, ...keys: K[]) {
    const target = {} as Pick<T, K>;
    for (let key of keys) if (key in source) target[key] = source[key];
    return target;
}

function myFunction(a: ArticleModel) {
    return pick(a, "title", "description", "body");
}
```

Pro: You get the autocompletion and the correct return type.

Con: magic strings.

Your IDE will not recognize these magic strings when you refactor/rename one of the properties. You'll have to do this manually, forgetting this may lead to bugs, or at least an error message, that the *(old)* string is not a valid property for the *(refactored)* object.

**Edit:**

Just saw that there is a [`nameof`-plugin for TS](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-nameof). So we could write:

```
function myFunction(a: ArticleModel) {
    return pick(a, nameof(a.title), nameof(a.description), nameof(a.body));
}
```

Pro: no magic strings anymore.

Con: Code gets pretty verbose again.

---

I guess, at this point it's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: thanks - but I don't like magic strings :)

Comment: I thought about trying something with a second parameter of type Partial<T>

On second thought this function would fail build if I use an invalid key - because of the "keyof"? That would make it acceptable from maintenance perspective

Comment: What's "magic" here?  Could you explain it?  On the code level, `a.title` and `a["title"]` mean the same thing, so I don't really see `a.title` as being any less "magic"al, unless I'm misunderstanding.